# Plot hole in Bioshock (Remastered Version)?

Tags: bioshock

I just finished the original Bioshock in remaster this wednesday , and then watched the director commentaries , then i realized there are some incostincencies between gameplay elements and story and logic.

so it is revealed that Atlas is in fact Frank Fontaine and has been controling your mind doing most of the stuff you did up until killing Andrew Ryan. this made me think , if Fontaine was controling Jack's mind , then why didn't he Force him to Harvest the little sisters and gave him the choice to either save them or harvest them? he clearly wants jack to eliminate Ryan and states Jack needs all the ADAM he can get to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Because neither you, or Frank, have access to the Little Sisters, and when you harvest, or save the sisters, you, and *only* you, get a small amount. This can't be transferred to another person, especially after Ryan breaks Frank's control over you.

Additionally, the Little Sisters are harvesting Adam for Fontaine already. When they harvest the Adam, they take it to Fontaine's hideout. Remember that there are *a lot* more Little Sisters crawling around all over the place - not just the ones that you encounter, and they harvest a lot more Adam then you gain from harvesting or saving them.

Comment: Yeah i get that but the thing is what  Fontaine wanted is for jack to take out ryan. For him to be able to do that according to Fontaine jack needs every bit of ADAM he can get his hands on . So even though the adam jack harvests or gets by saving Little Sisters doesn't go to Fontaine , since he wants jack to succeed , it would be neglegance if he let's jack decide on his own for this matter but control every other action of him.